# Non singular point in a variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've just came across the following definition:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n_k$ an affine variety of dimension $d$ and generators $f_1,...,f_m$. A point $x\in X$ is said to be nonsingular when the matrix $\left(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq m;\,1\leq j\leq n}$ has rank $n-d$.

I've tried some examples, like $C=Z(y^2-x^3)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_k$ in which this definition meets the geometric intuition: $C$ has dimension $1$ and is singular at $(0, 0)$, since the rank is $0\neq 2-1$ (this makes sense, because $(0,0)$ is a cusp).

But in the example $C'=Z(x^2, xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_k$, $C'$ is just a line (hence it has dimension $1$) and, by this definition, $(0,0)$ is singular, since the rank is $0\neq 2-1$.

Isn't this weird? How do I interpret that geometrically?

Comment: This make sense if you consider the _scheme_ defined by $x^2 = 0$ and not just the variety, but if you are just studying algebraic variety then as Kenny Wong said one should consider the radical of the ideal $(x^2,xy)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal corresponding to the line $C'$ is
$$ I(C') = \sqrt{(x^2, xy)} = (x).$$
So $x^2$ and $xy$ do not generate the ideal $I(C')$.

Instead, the ideal is generated by $x$, and the relevant Jacobian matrix is the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$
which has rank one at all points on $C'$.